# How to iterate just a single value in hashset in Java

Tags: hashset

I have entered 10 integer values in hashset in **JAVA**. I want to increase ***just*** the 4th integer in the set. How would i accomplish this?

Comment: Why would you use a hash set for this?

Comment: In hashset you can access elements only by iterator() or toArray(). Please cover my [HashSet tutorial](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/07/internal-life-of-hashset-in-java.html) to know what is HashSet internally.

Answer (score 0):

'Iterate a single value' is a contradiction in terms, and '4th Integer in the set' doesn't even have a well-defined meaning. You're using the wrong data structure if you need ordinality. Use an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Sets aren't ordered, so you don't have the concept of a 4th element. Use a list instead.

Note that you can use a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) instead, which maintains *insertion* order. That may work for you, but if you really want an ordering then a list is the way to go.